# Ajax tool kit AutoCompleteExtender and javascript

Tags: asp.net, ajax, autocompleteextender

I have an Ajaxtool kit AutoComplete extender control that targets to a Text box. I am calling a web service and returning the values to bind to the AutoComplete extender and that works great. I am really wondering about how I can retrieve the AutoCompleteextender control's Item values in javascript, when an Item is selected.

When an item is selected I am capturing the selected value in javascript function by calling the function in OnClientItemSelected attribute.

```
<pre>function CallJS(source, eventArgs) {
    alert('something got selected');
    alert(eventArgs.get_value());
}
```

But I am not sure using which Javascript property or object I can get hold of the list of values in the AutoComplete extender control?

Answer (score 1):

Use hidden field. U can store value in javascript and get it also in server side.

```
function ItemSelected(sender, EventArgs)
            {
                hid.value = EventArgs.get_value();
            }
```

Comment: Ok. This will get selected value from the list. But what if I wanted to get the list of items bound to that autocomplete extender at that time? That was my question.

Comment: r u using webservice or what for autocomplete

Comment: Yes I use a web service and it returns the list of values which is good. Now at any point when an item is selected from the control I wanted to fire a javascript which should be able to get hold of the list of items bound to the AutoCompleteExtender.

Comment: Can be flagged for deletion. Opened another question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515188/ajax-tool-kit-autocomplete-dropdown-usage-with-asp-net